# How to use "read -i" in FreeBSD? (prefilling users input)

Tags: linux, bash, freebsd

I wrote a bash-script in CentOs, but now I have an issue with this script in FreeBSD.

So the problem is in difference between "*read*" function in Linux and "*read*" function in FreeBSD.

---

This is a part of my script:

```
Tmp="an_num.tmp"
Tmpg=$(cat $Tmp)
Tmpi=$(expr $Tmpg + 1)
printf "${WONWARN} Please enter a number ${NORMAL} %s"
read -i "$Tmpi" -e Number; echo
echo "$Number" > "$Tmp"
```

Here I get a number from an_num.tmp (this file always contains only one number).

Then I Increment this number and put it in Tmpi variable.

After that, I use read function with prefilling (it prefills with Tmpi variable) and user can enter a new value or accept this incremented value.

---

*man read* from CentOS:

> -i text If  readline  is being used to read the line
>   text is placed into the editing buffer before editing begins.

But "*read*" in FreeBSD doesn'have the same *-i* key.

How can I use prefilling in FreeBSD OS?
Thank you.

---

> $ uname -a FreeBSD srv 11.0-RELEASE-p1 FreeBSD 11.0-RELEASE-p1 #0
>   r306420: Thu Sep 29 01:43:23 UTC 2016
>   root@releng2.nyi.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC amd64

Comment: This is not a difference between operating systems but between shells.  What shell are you using on each of the systems?

Comment: The `read -i` feature is `bash` specific, and only available in `bash` version 4.0 and above.

The Freebsd `sh` `read` builtin does not have this feature.

Comment: You are right, It was sh by default, so I changed my default SHELL to bash and succesfully execute it with bash.

Comment: @HelloKatty Just as I told you in your previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the script is executed by `bash` on both machines, there will be no issue (at least not if the installed versions of the shell both supports `read -i` and any other `bash`-specific feature that the script may use).

Make sure that the script has a proper `#!`-line pointing to the `bash` executable on each system.

---

Notes about the code:

```
Tmp="an_num.tmp"
Tmpg=$(cat $Tmp)       # may be replaced with Tmpg=$(<"$Tmp")
Tmpi=$(expr $Tmpg + 1) # may be replaced with Tmpi=$(( Tmpg + 1 ))

printf "${WONWARN} Please enter a number ${NORMAL} %s"
# The above lacks a value for the %s format string

read -i "$Tmpi" -e Number; echo
echo "$Number" > "$Tmp"
```

Alternative implementation (still `bash`-specific, but works with older versions since it avoids `read -i`, and it validates that the value read from the user is actually a number/decimal integer):

```
tmp_fname="an_num.tmp"

read num <"$tmp_fname"
num=$(( num + 1 ))

read -p 'Enter number: '

if [[ -n "$REPLY" ]] && [[ "$REPLY" =~ ^[0-9]*$ ]]; then
    num=$REPLY
fi

echo "$num" >"$tmp_fname"
```